# How to fix One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running?

Tags: magento2, linux

I am new to magento platform and I have installed magento on a shared linux server and when I logged into my admin panel I saw this message and I don't know how to set cron jobs on my linux server.

Answer (score 4):

You using terminal and enter command `bin/magento indexer:reindex`.
This command create new index of magento in your database.

You can read more about setup cron job in Magento2 at  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Answer (score 2):

To work with XAMPP installed on Windows,

First redirect to PHP folder in XAMPP by :

```
cd C:\xampp\php
```

Then enter following command :

```
php C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\bin\magento indexer:reindex
```

This will help you to remove the error.

Answer (score 1):

when you use wamp in windows7 for magento, you can open the cmd run as administrator and type code below to fix that warning.

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.4>php C:\wamp\www\magento2\bin\magento indexer:reindex
```

Note: Here, magento2 is project name

Answer (score 0):

C:\xampp\php>php C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\bin\magento indexer:reindex

run this command ... (magento2 is project name)

Comment: We have a [complete reference for cron](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/post-install-config.html#post-install-cron). You need it for running numerous processes and also for updating components or the core software.