# How can I Solve this problem the System display One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running.?

Tags: php

Display One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running.?

Answer (score 0):

Seems Cron jobs are not working. you need to set up cron jobs by following links  :

https://blog.amasty.com/configure-magento-cron-job/

http://opensourceforu.com/2017/02/magento-cron-dummies-configuration-cron-jobs/

you can cross check cron jobs are working or not by installing [AOE SCHEDULER extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html)

also same issue faced in below links :

[One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running. Not solved on mac](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125455/one-or-more-indexers-are-invalid-make-sure-your-magento-cron-job-is-running-no)

[How to fix One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92737/how-to-fix-one-or-more-indexers-are-invalid-make-sure-your-magento-cron-job-is)